# Is it Possible to Have Nutch Only Crawl Down a Certain File Path?

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I'm trying to user Apache nutch to only crawl down a certain file path. For example if my url is:

www.foo.com/shoes/

I would want to keep crawling urls like: www.foo.com/shoes/nike and www.foo.com/shoes/addidas and www.foo.com/shoes/addidas/soccer but NOT crawl the other directories like www.foo.com/clothes or www.foo.com/watches. Is there anyway nutch can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is to write a regex that matches to your pattern, something like

> +.www.foo.com/shoes/

and skip everything else by using

> -.*

at the end of your `crawl-urlfilter.txt`!